# Two totally different sites (on same server) getting mixed up in Google Search results

Tags: google-search, google-search-console, mismatch

We have two websites, both hosted on the same web server, but not sharing any other resources. However, we're getting strange issues where pages on one site will show up in search results as the other site.

- Site 1: farnam-custom.com
- Site 2: highlandbrewing.com

See this Google Search: 
[https://www.google.com/search?q=site:farnam-custom.com+highland](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=site:farnam-custom.com%20highland)

That shows a bunch of pages that do NOT exist on Site 1, but it's listing Site 1 as the domain. Clicking on those links takes you to that page on Site 2.

Also, in our Google Search Console (formerly Webmaster Tools) for Site 1, we're getting an ever increasing # of 404 errors reported, for URLs that exist on Site 2.

This is totally strange and I am so confused. If you have any ideas, please let me know!

Also, I found a thread where someone was having a similar issue, but didn't seem to see a resolution: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/iQmbVS2pfUE

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple reasons it could be there.

1) It was your original file structure when it was crawled by Google.

2) Check your sitemaps

3) Check internal links. Maybe external as well.

If it's not in your sitemaps our structure anymore (which it obvisouly isn't hence the 404) go into webmasters and have Google recrawl the URL. You can also go into blocked resources in webmasters and block the specific URLs. 401 redirects in .htaccess is also possible.

Comment: I've checked both sitemaps, and neither site links to either site. The two sites have totally different structures. Very few pages with the same URLs. Thanks for your ideas, but I don't think any of them are related to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a bad redirect on the server IP address that is sending a 404. That code suggests content exists but the server can't find it.

My suspicion is the records were merged into the closest matching records. In this case, Google couldn't resolve the IP for your second domain and merged it into your first. Google often tries to resolve both the IP and the domain when investigating URIs. You'll see this in your backlink profile from Webmaster where occasionally sites appear twice - once as an IP and once as a domain.

Fix the redirect on your IP address - have it go to somewhere with content or refuse the connection. Start using absolute URLs and canonical tags to prevent poor indexing. Then give Google time to fix the database.

Comment: Hi Yhorian. I'm sorry, but I don't really grasp what you're saying. What do you mean by "You've got a bad redirect on the server IP address that is sending a 404" and "he records were merged into the closest matching records"? Thanks for your help!

Comment: When you attempt to connect via port 80 on the IP address for your server - it tries to call up a resource it can't find, creating a 404.

Google records profiles for domains. When content and other metrics match closely, they're often merged as it assumes they're the same site and saves Google a lot of processing time and space. This creates quite a bit of odd behaviour from the index in certain situations.

Comment: Ok... how do I fix the redirect on my IP address? I do notice that when I go to https://192.64.55.248:443 (SSL port), it brings up a page on the farnam-custom.com site (Site 1). http://192.64.55.248:80 brings up a "404" page... Can you give me more details on how to 'fix' this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you on Apache? IIS? Nginx? It's your host settings. Might want to grab your server admin and check the configs.

Comment: I'm on Apache, on a Nexcess hosted server. When you say "check the configs", what should I be looking for? What configs? Pretend I know absolutely nothing ;)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I found that when I got a certificate from `letsencrypt` and started redirecting to the `https`, the site it started failing.

**Evidence:**

The last modified date on letsencrypt files in folder `/opt/letsencrypt` is `Mar 26`

Here is a chart of the site index status over time

[image: google index status drop]

**Potential solution:**

Add the `https` version as a [new google property](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68435/moving-from-http-to-https-google-search-console) in `Google Webmaster Tools`